# Hide Navigation (title) bar in Sharepoint 2013 Mobile view

Tags: sharepoint, mobile, responsive-design, styles, sharepoint-2013

I'm unable to find a way, how title bar (the one that reveals the menu, when clicked) can be hidden or styled. Trying to embed a custom CSS inside a script web-part did not result, as the script parts are disabled in Mobile view.

Can someone please recommend a way how the styling of Mobile View can be changed?

Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Maybe you could put your CSS on the AlternativePageHeader control with a delegate, or on the AlternateCSSUrl property of the SPWeb object. I don't think those two would get cut from the mobile view, but I have never tried it.

Regards.